# Any recommendations for learning about polyhedra and integer programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, reference-request, polyhedra, books

My knowledge on convex polyhedra and systems of linear inequalities (facets, edges, Farkas Lemma, projections, duality, etc.) is very scattered, and I'l like to go through a book to solidify it.

I'm looking to something similar to chapters 3-4 in Integer Programming by Conforti, Cornuejols, and Zambelli, but with lots of good exercises.

I have gone through some of Bertsimas' *Introduction to Linear Optimization*, and I can't really put my finger on why, but I just don't like it.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest *Fondations of Optimization* by O. Guler https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/foundations-of-optimization

Comment: [Integer Programming](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781119606475) by Wolsey is a classic, but not always super easy to read.

Comment: @user56202, do you see [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12532-016-0104-z)?